# What is the language FlowType uses to define interfaces?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[FlowType](http://flowtype.org/) interface files are declared using a certain language. [This page contains some examples](http://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#declarations). Where can I get an overview of the language, or an example of a lengthy interface file that demos all the available tokens/types/features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Quick Reference](http://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html) page in the docs is a good overview of all the language features.
The [lib directory](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/lib) in the Flow GitHub repository contains type definitions for the JavaScript standard library, DOM, React and Node which are good starting points.

There is a large degree of overlap between TypeScript and Flow's syntax, so the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) TypeScript definitions for your favorite library will give you something that will probably work in Flow with some small modifications. The biggest differences between the two for someone getting started are how you configure and run them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick overview:

```js
declare module ModuleName {
  ...more declare statements
}
declare module "QuotedModuleName" {
  ...more declare statements
}
declare module ModuleWithDefaultExport {
  // declare class exports or declare function exports also works
  declare var exports: exportType;
}
declare class ClassName {
  propertyName: propertyType;
  methodName(arg1: argType): returnType;
}
declare function functionName(arg1: argType): returnType;
declare var varName: varType;
interface InterfaceName {
  propertyName: propertyType;
  methodName(arg1: argType): returnType;
}
type TypeName = someType;
```

The flow binary ships with some library files embedded within it. These libraries specify some pretty basic things, like core JavaScript builtins, the DOM API, Node's API, etc. [You can browse those lib files on github.](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/lib)

Answer (score -2):

*declare module* and *declare class* that you see in the example page is in **TypeScript** : you can learn about the language at the official [site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Basically, Typescript use a more oriented-object syntax to write your javascript applications (in the end, it will compile your code to javascript).

Regarding the examples on how to work with Flow, you could find the [reference of Flow](http://flowtype.org/docs/quick-reference.html#_) and even find [examples](https://github.com/facebook/flow/tree/master/examples) in the Flow Github repo